# Making calls to a static library crashes my iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, static-libraries, xcode4.5, ios-frameworks

Since making the transition to XCode 4.5 and building with iOS 6 SDK my app crashes every time I make a call to a third party framework or static library .a file. Initially when I made the transition to XCode 4.5 these frameworks worked. The issue started popping up as I began updating the frameworks. After deleting the old version of the framework and adding the new one I would begin getting the crash on my simulator.

Running the code on the device works fine as expected but as soon as I make a call to any one of my third party frameworks or static libs on the simulator I'm doomed. Some of the frameworks that cause a crash are the Parse Framework, Socialize. The errors

Has anybody experienced this or hopefully found a solution? Testing on the device is slower but the real bummer is that I can't run any unit tests on my app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you updated the frameworks or static libraries:

- Are you sure that the APIs of these frameworks/libraries did not change in the meantime?
- Are you sure you added the frameworks in the "Link Binary With Libraries" again in your Build Phases of your application project, to link your app with the fmk/libs?
- Also be sure that the `-ObjC` flag is still present in your application's "Other Linker Flags" build settings, even if there is no reason not to if you had it already (as it worked before).

Besides, what is the crash log and error message when you call these methods?